# Use special characters in PHP mail() function

Tags: php, email, special-characters

I would like to send some special characters (like é, à, ü,...) by using the PHP mail() function. I tried this: (just a fragment of the code)

```
    $headers        = 'From: info@something.be';
    $header_        = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

    $to         = "me@gmail.com";
    $subject        = 'Confirmation de commande';
    $message        = "Bonjour $firstname";


     if (mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $headers)) {...
```

But for some reason, all I get is things like sâÃ©lÃ¨ve. Advice?

Comment: Please define "doesn't work."

Comment: It just send the characters like passÃ© and sâÃ©lÃ¨ve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you set your internal encoding to UTF8 with [iconv_set_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-set-encoding.php).

Comment: @Michiel: Say `iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");` at the top of your script, like in the example.